# Unique and Not null constraints for all columns related with some entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

I have one `@Entity e1,` which can be `@JoinColumn` of another `@Entity`. In all cases I have to write `@JoinColumn(name="e1", unique = true)` and `@NotNull` constaints.

Maybe there is a way to automate this actions (write something in e1 class, for example)? I.e. apply these constraints to all columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some workaround. It's `@MappedSuperclass` annotation. I.e. now I solved this promblem through extending.